# Swift functions with numeric variables

Tags: swift

If I have 4 variables:

```
var team1 = 0
var team2 = 0
var team3 = 0
var team4 = 0
```

Is there any way of writing a function, with an input of an integer, that will allow me to do something like

```
func AddPointsToTeam(TeamNumber: Int) {
 TeamX += 1
}
```

I know I could do this using arrays, and use the input as the index for the array, but is there any way of doing it this way?

Comment: If you mean to change the value of parameter you will have to use `inout` before parameter.

Comment: Would a series of `if`-clauses, or a `switch`-statement be allowed by the rules?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are looking to create a variable name by appending the incoming `Int` to `"team"` like you can with strings. If this is the case, then no, there is no way to do what you are attempting. Is there some reason to not use an array? It would make things much easier. Otherwise you have to `switch` based on the incoming `Int` and pick the right `var` that way.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Okay, yeah im struggling to word my question. If i could word it perfectly i would just google it and know the answer :) Thank you for the help though ill just use arrays

Comment: Google too will bring you here on SO. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because it's not clear what do you want exactly to do... or what you will expect.

For example I used dictionaries.

```
var teamsDictionary:[String:Int] = ["team1":0,"team2":0,"team3":0,"team4":0]

print("Count of Team 1: \(teamsDictionary["team1"])") //prints 0
teamsDictionary["team1"] = 4
print("Count of Team 1: \(teamsDictionary["team1"])") //prints 4
```

Also you can use `Sets` or `Arrays` as well. Have a look into the documentation to get inspiration https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Use camel case when you create your fuctions in swift, same for variables.

> You write an in-out parameter by placing the inout keyword right before a parameter’s type. An in-out parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to replace the original value.

```
func addPointsToTeam(_ teamNumber: inout Int) {
   teamNumber += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your exact question, yes it is possible. It is incredibly unlikely that you want to do this, but it is possible as long as you put this in a subclass of `NSObject` and tag everything as `@objc`, then you can use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/):

```
import Foundation

class League: NSObject {
    @objc var team1: Int = 0  // Fun-fact: If you fail to include @objc here
    @objc var team2: Int = 0  // it will compile fine, but it'll crash later.
    @objc var team3: Int = 0  // Using the ObjC runtime takes away many of the
    @objc var team4: Int = 0  // compiler protections that Swift offers.

    // This is an advanced technique that should almost never be used in Swift
    func addPointsToTeam(number: Int) {
        let key = "team\(number)"
        let oldValue = value(forKey: key) as! Int
        setValue(oldValue + 1, forKey: key)
    }
}

let league = League()
league.addPointsToTeam(number: 1)
```

But using KVC and hand-built selectors is almost certainly not the tool you want. Even in ObjC where KVC is used commonly, hand-building selectors like this is rare and dangerous and generally only used for advanced tooling.

The tool you want is an array. Don't use four variables when you mean a list. Use one variable:

```
var teamScores = [0, 0, 0, 0]

func addPointsToTeam(number: Int) {
    teamScores[number] += 1
}
```

Very quickly you will discover that you have multiple, parallel arrays like `teamScores` and `teamNames`. At that point you should fix your data again. As before, don't use multiple variables when you mean one:

```
struct Team {
    let name: String
    var score: Int
}

var teams = [Team(name: "Alices", score: 0), Team(name: "Bobs", score: 0)]

func addPointsToTeam(number: Int) {
    teams[number].score += 1
}
```

Note that arrays are 0-indexed. So if you want to line up with "1, 2, 3, 4" you'll need to subtract or add one as necessary.

Comment: One question... In first example when using KVC how can we add dynamic score like 5, 4 to any team as the key itself is `team+number`?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You can add any score you like in the line `setValue(oldValue + 1, forKey: key)`. That just adds one point since that's what the original function does. You could set it to anything.

Comment: Yeah it is just adding one point. I was looking for a dynamic score here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to use an enum for the team, it would make it clearer how to use the function.

```
enum Team: Int {
  case team1 = 1
  case team2
  case team3
  case team4
}

struct TeamPoints {
  var team1 = 0
  var team2 = 0
  var team3 = 0
  var team4 = 0

  mutating func addPoint(forTeam team:Team) {
    switch team {
    case .team1:
      team1 += 1
    case .team2:
      team2 += 1
    case .team3:
      team3 += 1
    case .team4:
      team3 += 1
    }
  }
}
```